# Power BI 3 tier hierarchy with multiple tiered columns

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-modeling

This is my first time working with hierarchies, and of course its a pretty niche scenario i can't find much information on.. Basically, i'm having some trouble getting the visualization I expect from Power BI, specifically leveraging the matrix visual.  The data is in the current format.

[image: current_format]

I want to be able to drill down into each level and see the different pieces of information specific to that ID instead of what ever is the first instance.  An example of the desired output would look something like this (note, this has been done manually).

[image: desired_output]

I'm thinking I probably need to transpose the data and have a new column that identifies the hierarchy?  Maybe something like this? But not 100% sure this would be the right approach.

[image: possible_transposition]

I've tried the current formatted data in matrix in power bi, but as the title is across multiple rows it doesn't look like what I'm after.  I've tried some formula using IF statements but again because of the format, it doesn't work.

[image: powerbi_current]

I've tried to put the formatted dataset in image 2 into a matrix, which fixes the title and status issues.  But then fails in the hierarchy as it isn't layered into 3 tiers.

[image: powerbi_formatted]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get the table into the format below, where parent ID is the key that connects one key to another.  All parent ids, must exist in the key field, so for the top level, I just set it to the highest possible tier, 1 in this example.

[image]

Next create 2 columns using PATH and PATHLENGTH.  More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax

PATH = PATH('Table'[key], 'Table'[parent id])

PATHLENGTH = PATHLENGTH('Table'[PATH])

[image]

Form your hierarchy around PATHLENGTH as the top tier in a matrix view and place key underneath it.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide an explanation in text as well as screenshots. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)